# Error with Firing Events from Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I'm trying to add swipe function to the mobile version of my website ..

by using  **TouchSwipe** plugin see this [link](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Single_swipe.html)

this is the code user to catch **swipeLeft** event

```
$(".slider img").swipe(function(){
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        clearTimeout(timerSlider_id);
        var $current = $('.get_data_from').removeClass('get_data_from');
        var $next = $current.next();
        if($next.length == 0) $next = $('.slider_bottom .section:first-child');

        $next.addClass('get_data_from');

        slider_load_data();
        timerSlider_id = setTimeout(slider_rotation,7000);
    }
});
```

but it doen't work .. can anyone help me in solving this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful question. What does it do differently from what it's supposed to do? Do you get error messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: it doesn't work and the rest of the code below this section dosn't work, the code stop at this section, thanks Barmar

Comment: That usually means there's a syntax error in this code, this should show up in the developer tools.

Comment: I don't know what is the error, and ask to get help :(

Comment: Use your debugger, it should tell you where the error is.

Comment: i use chrome inspect element and it doesn't show any error, and you suggest another way

Comment: Inspect element is for viewing the DOM, you want to look for errors in the Source tab.

Comment: this is the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and flag this line swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `.swipe()` is an object, not a function. It should be:

```
$(".slider img").swipe({
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        clearTimeout(timerSlider_id);
        var $current = $('.get_data_from').removeClass('get_data_from');
        var $next = $current.next();
        if($next.length == 0) $next = $('.slider_bottom .section:first-child');

        $next.addClass('get_data_from');

        slider_load_data();
        timerSlider_id = setTimeout(slider_rotation,7000);
    }
});
```

You had correct syntax for an object, but you had it in the body of a function where a statement was expected.